# global.asax to check for files in a folder and copy if the folder is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

I have a MVC3 application with some XML files on the App_Data folder. To prevent these files been overwritten with the new builds, the team responsible for the publication to the web suggest to add some code in the Global.asax file to check, when the application starts, if the files on App_Data already exists, and then update the files from other folder (XML_Templates) ONLY if they NOT exist on the App_Data folder. 
Any suggestion how can I code this logic in the Global.asax file? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should invest some time in interacting with your other questions to help resolve and mark them as answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...

    var appData = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "app_data");
    var xmlTemplates = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "XML_Templates");

    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(xmlTemplates))
    {
        var dest = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(file));
        if (!File.Exists(dest))
        {
            File.Copy(file, dest);
        }
    }
}
```